# Packaging Python applications with PyQt and PyQwt (for Linux only)

Tags: python, linux, distribution, pyqt4

This is a follow-on from my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690383/using-pyqt4-with-bbfreeze-wrong-ui-style-used); I think I will have to look at a different method.

I want to package my Python program with some of its dependencies. I'm aware of tools like cx_Freeze or bbfreeze, but as you can see in the linked question they have issues for my situation.

I don't want my users to have to install my application using the super user.

What I would really like is to package PyQt4 and PyQwt with my application, but use the system Python and other system libraries. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried pyinstaller, http://www.pyinstaller.org/ ?

Comment: Wow that looks great, going to give it a try right now. Amazing I never came across it from googling.

Comment: +1 on pyinstaller. I use it for a pyqt app as well in linux.